# When will launchpad.net be working?

Tags: 14.04, launchpad

launchpad.net has been up and down like a yo-yo for the last two days, making my weekends migration of 40 machines to 14.04 impossible.

see http://www.isitdownrightnow.com/launchpad.net.html

Anybody have an idea when it will be available consistently?

Comment: this question cannot be answered directly it depends when they gonna fix it. you can watch their status on their official [twitter](https://twitter.com/launchpadstatus)

Comment: thanks but I was hoping for something more accurate, I mean they say it's fixed, then they say it'll be down for 20mins- 2 hours ago, very frustrating.

Comment: really stuff as essential as this should have a failover CDN

Comment: everything is back to normal. it's just temporary.